# How to decline North Rhein-Westphalia (Северный Рейн-Вестфалия)

Tags: склонение, composite-nouns

I am not certain how to decline it. Wikipedia has no problem with that, and declines all three words independently: **в Северном Рейне-Вестфалии**. However, intuitively *Рейн-Вестфалия* seems to be a composite noun. Due to this, I believe I've heard in use *Северная Рейн-Вестфалия*, *в Северной Рейн-Вестфалии*, which is probably wrong. So, are there any clear rules for this case? If possible, please give other examples of such combinations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of this land contains not a hyphen, but [a long dash](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%D1%E5%E2%E5%F0%ED%FB%E9+%D0%E5%E9%ED-%C2%E5%F1%F2%F4%E0%EB%E8%FF), that's why it's not a composite noun. The land was formed by merging Westfalen (Вестфалия) and the nothern part of Rheinprovinz (Рейнская провинция), so it consists of 2 parts, Северный Рейн *and* Вестфалия.

One should [decline all the 3 words](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%C6%E8%F2%E5%EB%FC+%D1%E5%E2%E5%F0%ED%EE%E3%EE+%D0%E5%E9%ED-%C2%E5%F1%F2%F4%E0%EB%E8%E8) in the name of this land:

**Им.**  `Северный Рейн – Вестфалия`

**Род.** `Северного Рейна – Вестфалии`

**Дат.** `Северному Рейну – Вестфалии`

**Тв.**  `Северным Рейном – Вестфалией`

**Пр.**  `Северном Рейне – Вестфалии`

**Вин.** `Северный Рейн – Вестфалию`

That is why, the correct form is:

> В Северном Рейне – Вестфалии
>
> Из Северного Рейна – Вестфалии

Alternatively, if one does not want to decline the 3 words, one can use the generic name, `земля` (land), before it, then only the word `земля` is declined:

> В земле Северный Рейн – Вестфалия
>
> Из земли Северный Рейн – Вестфалия

It is this last way of saying it, with the word `земля`, that is used most often in Russian texts.

Comment: Great! Thanks for finding these Spravka's answers and for the detailed answer.